# ide and application server for java

Tags: java, servlets

Which is the best application server and the best ide for an absolute beginner for locally hosting servlets

Comment: Eclipse and Tomcat is the way to go. Other tutorials here: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

Comment: is tomcat really an AS? I thought you can host only servlet based application within tomcat

Comment: probably the best integrated solution nowadays is netbeans that comes with integrated glassfish server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One good solution is [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) + [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

Check this [screencast](http://keyboardsamurais.de/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/eclipse-wtp-tutorial.htm) for further information.

Comment: As far as I know Tomcat is not an application server but a web server

Comment: You don't need a full blown application server for hosting servlets - just a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty

Comment: @Shervin are you kidding me?Tomcat is an open source servlet container!!Why DOWNVOTE??

Comment: Because Tomcat is NOT and I emphasize on NOT an Application Server. Instead of bashing me and down voting my answer you should read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse and netbeans each have a distribution that includes all you need for Servlet development, including a server.

Between the two, eclipse is the more powerful, but for a beginner it could be a bit overwhelming. Netbeans is less configurable, but that also means there's less to distract you from the "normal" way of doing things, which is probably the best for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend NetBeans + Apache Tomcat/Jetty is you're just looking into servlet development. If you plan to do some EJB3/3.1 development as well have a look at Glassfish or JBoss AS.

NetBeans integrates great with all of these and requires far less configuration than Eclipse to get you started.

You might consider as an IDE option IntelliJ IDEA as well, it's heavier that Eclipse and NetBeans, but it has some compelling features of its own...

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using [Eclipse Java EE version](http://www.jboss.org/tools), together with JBoss Application Server. You can download [Eclipse](http://www.jboss.org/tools) plugin: [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) which adds alot of nice plugins to [Eclipse](http://www.jboss.org/tools).

You can download [JBoss AS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas) (Application Server) for free.
All products are free and opensource.

Comment: In my opinion - absolutely not. JBoss is no place to get started with just servlets, but everybody has their own opinion on the subject. You actually need only the JBoss Web from JBoss AS, which is a heavily modified Apache Tomcat...

Comment: -1 JBoss for beginner?You got to be kidding me!And you commented on my answer that Tomcat is a web server!

Comment: JBoss AS is modified from Apache Tomcat. @abson asked for the best application server for a beginner. I can't see why JBoss isn't the best. Glassfish? Websphere? With JBoss, you get a lot of configuration for free which you don't need with Tomcat for instance.

Comment: It's safe to assume that an absolute beginner does not understand the distinction between an J2EE application server and a servlet container, and the desire for "locally hosting servlets" strongly suggests that he really just needs a servlet container.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: This is totally stupid. Just because you make an assumption that @abson doesn't know the difference between an application server and web container you are downvoting my answer?
If you think that @abson should be aware of this, then you should comment or answer that. Not downvote a totally ligit answer which he already as accepted.

Comment: @abson Absolutely not!Jboss is not for beginner.What you need is a lightweight servlet container.